# Deserialize JSON String using org.codehaus.jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to serializing and deserializing JSON.

I have String with value

```
String json = [{"Area":"LoremIpsum","Quantity":1500,"isSubArea":false},
{"Area":"LoremIpsum","Quantity":700,"isSubArea":false}];
```

which i want to deserialize, i used ObjectMapper of Jackson to deserialize

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<DeserializeJSON> agentsList = mapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<List<DeserializeJSON>>() {});
```

My deserialize Class

```
public class DeserializeJSON {
String Area;
Integer Quantity = 0;
boolean isSubArea = false;

public String getArea() {
    return Area;
}
public void setArea(String Area) {
    this.Area = Area;
}
public Integer getQuantity() {
    return Quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(Integer Quantity) {
    this.Quantity = Quantity;
}
public boolean isSubArea() {
    return isSubArea;
}
public void setSubArea(boolean isSubArea) {
    this.isSubArea = isSubArea;
}
```

}

But i am getting Error

```
Unrecognized field "Area" (Class DeserializeJSON), not marked as ignorable at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2acf7a; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: DeserializeJSON["Area"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Jackson will use property accessors in [JavaBean naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) rather than fields. To make your example work, you can change this by adding

```
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY));
```

Have a look at the other methods on `VisibilityChecker` to customise your json mapping correctly.

Comment: Thanks ryanp, Cant i change the DeserializeJSON Class so that i dont have to set visibilityChecker,Actually i have checked with different combinations but didn't find working.

Comment: @Sushant - yes you can, and I'd recommend you do because field names starting with a capital letter are peculiar anyway. Look into customising the mapping with e.g. the `@JsonProperty` annotation on your accessors.